# acrobat script to perform an organize pages and then replace

Tags: javascript, powershell, adobe, acrobat

I have an OLDFOLDER with hundreds of PDF files in it.  I am currently having to open each file, click **Organize Pages > Replace >** Then I select the new file from the NEWFOLDER.

Is there a way to do this via a script?  Files in both folders have the same filename.

i.e. c:\OLDFOLDER\OFD_01A.pdf = c:\NEWFOLDER\OFD_01A.pdf
I now perform the operation of opening the OldFolder version and replacing it with the new one.  This is done to preserve links in the files.

Any thoughts to get me going?  The code below is returning an error in the debugger, but I dont know why.

```
    var doc = app.openDoc({
    cPath: "/C/Users/21194/Documents/Test/Old_Map_Pages/OFD_11F.pdf"
});
    doc.replacePages({
    nPage: 1,
    cPath: "/C/Users/21194/Documents/Test/New_Map_Pages/OFD_11F.pdf",
    nStart: 1,
    nEnd: 1
});
```

TypeError: Invalid argument type.
Doc.replacePages:8:Console undefined:Exec
===> Parameter nPage.
undefined

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Acrobat currently installed, so this is from parts of API, see: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/jsdevguide/JS_Dev_PDFCreation.html?highlight=replacepages#extracting-moving-deleting-replacing-and-copying-pages

So try this for starters:

NOTE I have presumed the input is a single page cover sheet. If that is the case, since pages are index base [0], then the page to be replaced is `0`. Amend 0's to 1 if I am wrong.

```
var srcFile = "/C/Users/21194/Documents/Test/Old_Map_Pages/OFD_11F.pdf"; //old input file
var inFile = "/C/Users/21194/Documents/Test/Old_Map_Pages/Cover.pdf"; //replacement 1st page [0]
var outFile = "/C/Users/21194/Documents/Test/New_Map_Pages/OFD_11F.pdf"; //new output file

doc = app.openDoc({ cPath: srcFile });
this.replacePages({
    nPage: 0,
    cPath: inFile,
    nStart: 0,
    nEnd: 0
});
newDoc.saveAs({ cPath: outFile });
newDoc.closeDoc(true); // Close it without notice
```

Note you should also close the source doc otherwise it will be left hanging (locked) open.